# Fixed-effects generalized linear model for multinomial data

Tags: r, glm, multinomial, glmm

I would like to find an equivalent fixed-effects model in R for the `ordinal` package model for analyzing multinomial data with threshold terms and a "probit" link function, such as:

```
clmm(y ~ 1 + Bloco + (1| Trat), data=dados3a, link="probit")
```

The function  below does not calculate the threshold terms.

```
glm(y ~ Bloco + Trat, data = data, family = binomial(link = "probit"))
```

I would appreciate some help in finding out if there is an equivalent function to solve this problem.

My attempt was with ordinal data on a scale of grades, from one to five.

Comment: maybe something here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/